# Preg_match_all with s pattern modifier doesn't work properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to match all content between `<!-- and -->`

My php code:

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTML
<!-- content
content content
content -->
<!-- dd  dsd  sdsd  s -->
<!-- dsajda2i -->
HTML;
preg_match_all('#<!-- (.*) -->#si',$html,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($out);
?>
```

but it doesn't match it properly.

**OBS:** i can have any character inside `<!-- here any characters -->`.

can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `(.*?)` instead of just `(.*)`. The default "greedy" behavior of the regex engine would otherwise yield unexpected results.

Comment: @user1626454 Alternatively, you can use the `U` modifier to reverse the greediness across the whole expression (i.e. `.*?` would become greedy when you use this modifier)